# Using easy_install3 with ansible

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ansible

It seems `easy_install3` is not currently available as an ansible module.  So instead of doing this:

```
---
  - name: Install apt dependencies
    apt: name={{item}} state=installed
    with_items:
      - python3-setuptools

  - name: install pip3
    easy_install3: name=pip
```

I'm using this:

```
---
  - name: Install apt dependencies
    apt: name={{item}} state=installed
    with_items:
      - python3-setuptools

  - name: install pip3
    shell: easy_install3 pip
```

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Why not just use apt to install `python-pip`?

Comment: I chose this route using `- python3-pip`.  Thanks @ydaetskcoR  If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Are you aware that pip has been bundled with Python since 3.4? Or are you purposefully installing an old version of Python3?

Comment: Didn't seem to be on my command line @ydaetskcoR ... likely I just made a mistake, but was an Ubuntu 14.04 box I first provisioned about 6 months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can just use apt to install `python3-pip` rather than going via `easy_install` like the dark old days:

```
---
  - name: Install apt dependencies
    apt: name=python3-pip state=installed
```

If you did need to force a specific executable for [`easy_install`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/easy_install_module.html) then you could use the `executable` option:

```
  - name: install pip3
    easy_install: name=pip
    executable: easy_install-3.3
```

However, it might also help to know that pip has been bundled with Python [since 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-453) so you might not need to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think `executable` option can be used to mention the version of easy_install. However(as suggested in the comments), it is recommended to use the `pip` module which you can first install using `easy_install`.

See: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/easy_install_module.html for more information.